# Django is not serving media files uploaded by user on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have tried everything but somehow i cannot see images uploaded by user.I have deployed code on heroku and every static file is getting loaded properly. User is even going to correct path of image  but somehow server is showing errors of not finding image.

```
Settings.py
 # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
#)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Models.py
#this is for photos upload by user
class You(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,default='pictures/videos')
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

#Views.py(To upload files)
@login_required
def upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        newdoc = You(docfile = request.FILES['file'],user=request.user)
        newdoc.save()
        msg='dee'
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': msg}))

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()



    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,'mat_upload.html',{'form':form})

Template(gallery.html)
{% for document in documents %}
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/media/{{ document.docfile }}" alt="hiiii" style="max-width: 100%;
    height: 250px;" />
{% endfor %}

@login_required
def gallery(request):
    documents =  You.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request,'gallery.html',{'documents': documents,})
Urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
admin.autodiscover()

import harpoons.views


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('harp.urls')),
    url(r'^password_reset_recover/', include('password_reset.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),




]
```

Comment: Did you do python manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: @alejosocorro Yes i did collectstatic. Issue is with media files uploaded by user.They are getting uploaded but django is throwing error when i open them even location seems correct

Answer (score 8):

You cannot save user-uploaded files locally on Heroku. The filesystem is ephemeral, and does not persist across dyno restarts or between concurrent dynos. You need to upload them somewhere more permanent; a popular choice is Amazon S3, and there are plenty of libraries that will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but still i should see images till dyno is running

Comment: Only if you actually configured something to serve them from /media/. WhiteNoise, which you presumably are using to serve static assets, only serves at STATIC_URL by default.